# Manage iOS popups with bluetooth device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, popup

Is there a possibility to select "OK"/"another option" answer in iOS system popups when an external entry device is connected using by this device?

I'm using Bluetooth device (iRig BluetTurn/iRig BlueBoard). This is a device connecting via Bluetooth (one as a keyboard, another with different protocol). They have 2 or 4 buttons. I am using it as next/previous buttons to navigate the app, because the user cannot use his hands. It's working perfectly, but if iOS shows a popup (eg. that there's new software update) the user is blocked, because he can't dismiss it (can't touch screen).

I strongly doubt it, but does anyone have an idea that it would be possible to answer these iOS system popup questions via external bluetooth device? I want to point I'm not a manufacturer of this device, I can't change how the buttons respond.